# How to check whether two S-expressions are structurally identical in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm not entirely sure on how to approach this. I think I want to go through x and y individually with a helper function and have that helper fuction return a value depending on what it finds and then compare them in (structurally? x y). However, I can think of multiple ways using that approach can go wrong.

```
define (structurally? x y) 
(
...
)
```

example:

```
(structurally? quote(1 2 (3 a 5) (b 6 c "string" 7 (5)) 9)      
               quote(2 1 (3 "string" 5) (b 6 c a 7 (5)) 9))
```

the result is #t

```
 (structurally? '(1 2 (3 a b 5) (b 6 c "string" 7 (5)) 9)
                '(2 1 (3 "string" 5) (b 6 c d a 7 (5)) 9))
```

the result is #f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, we have to simultaneously traverse both lists of lists, taking special care with the edge cases. If we manage to traverse the lists without one of them ending before the other, then we can say that they're structurally equal. Try this:

```
(define (structurally? exp1 exp2)
        ; if we reach the end of both lists, they're equal
  (cond ((and (null? exp1) (null? exp2)) #t)
        ; if we reach the end of one before the other, they're distinct
        ((and (null? exp1) (not (null? exp2))) #f)
        ; if we reach the end of one before the other, they're distinct
        ((and (not (null? exp1)) (null? exp2)) #f)
        ; if we find an atom they're equal, no matter its value
        ((not (pair? exp1)) #t)
        ; recursive step: advance over `car` and `cdr` of both lists
        ; simultaneously, combining all partial results using `and`
        (else
         (and (structurally? (car exp1) (car exp2))
              (structurally? (cdr exp1) (cdr exp2))))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(structurally? '(1 2 (3 a 5) (b 6 c "string" 7 (5)) 9)
               '(2 1 (3 "string" 5) (b 6 c a 7 (5)) 9))
=> #t

(structurally? '(1 2 (3 a b 5) (b 6 c "string" 7 (5)) 9)
               '(2 1 (3 "string" 5) (b 6 c d a 7 (5)) 9))
=> #f
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking at this for hours

Comment: what are applications of such a check?

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Óscar López can be simplified in this way:

```
(define (structurally? exp1 exp2)
     (cond ((not (pair? exp1)) (not (pair? exp2)))
           ((not (pair? exp2)) #f)
           (else (and (structurally? (car exp1) (car exp2))
                      (structurally? (cdr exp1) (cdr exp2))))))
```

In the first branch of `cond` we say that if the first expression is not a pair, than the result of the function is the result of checking if also the second expression is not a pair. This is also one of the final cases of the recursion, since you cannot recur on a non-pair value.

In the second branch we know that `exp1` is a pair, so if `exp2` is not a pair, the expressions are not structurally equivalent. And this is the other final case of the recursion.

Finally, the recursive case is equal to the other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see why the examples you gave are true and false, but I am not sure what the resulting expression tree looks like. Let's say you have expression `e`, for example the math expression `(+ (+ 2 4) 5)`. The root, `+` is `(car e)`, the left tree, `(+ 2 4)` is `(cadr e)`, and the right tree, `5` is `(caddr e)`. Structurally, that expression is the same as `(+ (- 3 7) 1)`, but the evaluated result is different...

If you navigate your expression and have no `c(a)dr` or `c(a)ddr`, you have reached the end of the traversal in that direction.

You may need a helper method, but I imagine something to the effect of `(and (equal? (car x) (car y)) (structurally? (cdr x) (cdr y)) (structurally? (cddr x) (cddr y)))` will get you started.